# Create JPanel with GridBagLayout and JPanels on each column

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt

I'm trying to create `JPanel` with `GridBagLayout` and panels on each column.
But when I run the program, I always get just one panel on the grid although I have a loop to create 10X10 panels.

### ColumnPanel

```
public class BoardColumnPanel extends JPanel {

public BoardColumnPanel() {
    this.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    this.setSize(48, 48);
}
}
```

### Grid view

```
public class BoardPanel extends JPanel {

private GridBagLayout layout;

public BoardPanel() {
    initBoardPanel();
}

private void initBoardPanel() {
    layout = new GridBagLayout();
    this.setLayout(layout);
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    // fill grid
    BoardColumnPanel column;
    for (int row=0;row<10;row++) {
        for (int col=0; col < 10; col++) {
            column = new BoardColumnPanel();
            gridBagConstraints.gridx = col;
            gridBagConstraints.gridy = row;
            gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 5;
            gridBagConstraints.ipady = 5;
            layout.setConstraints(column,gridBagConstraints);
            this.add(column);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), notice by using this [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) every [JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) will have the same Size on the screen,

Comment: Gridlayout prints just one panel on the top left. :(

Answer (score 2):

Your code is OK. Let's change the background color of `BoardColumnPanel`:

```
public class BoardColumnPanel extends JPanel {

  public BoardColumnPanel(int i) {

        this.setBackground(new Color(10 * i, 10 * i, 10 * i));
        this.setSize(48, 48);
    }
}
```

and initialize it with different shade of grey:

```
public class BoardPanel extends JPanel {

  private GridBagLayout layout;

  public BoardPanel() {

    initBoardPanel();
  }

  private void initBoardPanel() {

    layout = new GridBagLayout();
    this.setLayout(layout);
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    // fill grid
    BoardColumnPanel column;
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
        column = new BoardColumnPanel(row + col);
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = col;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = row;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 5;
        gridBagConstraints.ipady = 5;
        layout.setConstraints(column, gridBagConstraints);
        this.add(column);
      }
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.getContentPane().add(new BoardPanel());

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't Elad. Boris's example prints 10x10 grid with different shades of gray for each panel. He changed the colors so you can see that there's more than one panel. I just ran it. (crap...I accidentally +1 Elad's comment...sorry Boris)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but I'd say 
GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
needs to be *inside* the for loops.
Else you're repeatedly setting gridx/gridy for the same constraint.